# How to try open files unless no exception?

Tags: python, loops, exception

I have this code to consolidate thousands of csv file from folder (Box Drive folder) however time to time I get permission error on some of the files. When I start code over it is fine. But this error pops up more less randomly with random file in directory.

What I need to do is to just wait few seconds and try to open that file again (not skip it)

So far I have this but not working as expected:

```
with open(OutputTo, "wb") as fout:
    with open(sampleFile, "rb") as f:   # first file to get header
        fout.write(f.read())  
    for fs in toLoad:                  # now the rest
        with open(path + fs, "rb") as f:
            #while True: # infinite loop
            try:
                next(f) # skip the header
                fout.write(f.read())
            except PermissionError:
                #second try usually works. 
                failed = failed + 1 # counter
                if failed > 10: 
                    print('\n Script failed more than 10 time so I stopped it.')
                    break
                else:
                    print('\n Perm error, trying again in 5 sec.')
                    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: The "while True" is basically the right idea (but should better wrap the "with" than to be in it). At the end of the code in the try-block place a "break" to exit the loop if all is well. The check of "failed" count should be repeated outside of the while-loop to break the enclosing for-loop.

Comment: For efficiency matters i would make a list of all file names that got a permission denied error and then handle them separately after you are done going over all of the available files. In terms of the logic of your time wait there are some good answers here so I think you will manage

Answer (score 0):

By surrounding the file opening inside a `while True` loop with a try catch block, and waiting *n* seconds when PermissionError shows up. Be careful though, if you don't want to skip the file, you have to be sure the PermissionError is just a temporary thing, otherwise you end up in an endless loop constantly retrying (I would implement a break to stop after *n* tries)

```
import glob, time
 filenames = glob.glob('*.csv')
 for file in filenames:
     while True:
         try:
             hndl = open(file,"rb")
             # Do stuff
             break
         except PermissionError:
             time.sleep(5)
             hndl.close()
             continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I made couple of changes according to @Michael Butscher's comment. (credit to him)

*btw code never failed more than twice.*

```
with open(OutputTo, "wb") as fout:
    with open(sampleFile, "rb") as f:   # first file to get header
        fout.write(f.read())  
    for fs in toLoad:                  # now the rest
        while True: # infinite loop
            with open(path + fs, "rb") as f:
                try:
                    next(f) # skip the header
                    fout.write(f.read())
                    #status
                    sys.stdout.write('\r') # overwrite in place
                    expectedTime = round((((time.time() - startTime)/(toLoad.index(fs)+1))*(len(toLoad) - toLoad.index(fs)))/60,2) # based on how it went so far 
                    percentage = round((toLoad.index(fs)/(len(toLoad)+1))*100,2)  # number of done files relative to all files (after date filter)
                    success = success + 1 # counter
                    sys.stdout.write('completed {} perc. expected time to end: {} minutes, success: {}, failed: {}'.format(percentage, expectedTime, success, failed)) # status
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    failed = 0 # reset counter if success
                    break
                except PermissionError:
                    #second try always works. Script waits 5 seconds and usually run ok.
                    failed = failed + 1 # counter
                    print('\n Perm error, trying again in 5 sec. ({})'.format(path + fs))
                    time.sleep(5)
        if failed > 10: 
            print('\n Script failed more than 10 time so I stopped it.')
            break
```